# Magento Use Web Server Rewrites Not Working At All

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I have just put Magento 1.8.1.0 onto my server hosted with Digital Ocean.

I’ve put “Use Web Server Rewrites” to yes and all links result in a 404 Not Found. The directory of Magento is in /var/www/sitename.com/public_html/. There is a default Magento `.htaccess` in there. The server also has `mod_rewrite` enabled. Also the apache conf has `AllowOverride All`

I’ve tried for about 8 hours many different `.htaccess` files and conf’s and nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Have you indexed or re-indexed the Catalog URL Rewrites? The Magento Web Server Rewrites are actually handled by the Magento application - they are not handled in `.htaccess` so modifying `.htaccess` won't help.

I recommend you revert to the original `.htaccess`, set your Magento theme to the default theme, re-index the catalog URL rewrites, clear the cache for good measure, and try again.

If it still isn't working, inspect your database table core_url_rewites. There should be a lot of rows in this table - like three for every product in your store - and some rows will rewrite to categories and most will rewrite to products. Here is an example product rewrite row to help you identify if that table has the correct the data:

`139349     2   product/2866/79     topcatname/subcatname/producturlkey.html    catalog/product/view/id/2866/category/79    1   NULL    NULL    79  2866`

If that table looks like it has the correct data then to continue tracing this bug you should interrogate the function:

```
//file: app/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php
//class: Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front
    public function dispatch(){
      //...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Enabling module rewrite and restarting Apache did the trick for me.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can see which modules you have loaded with:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

Should see something like this if the rewrite module is enabled:

```
....
negotiation_module (shared)
php5_module (shared)
rewrite_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
....
```